# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException, Could not read document: Unrecognized token

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to do a POST request to an API. When I do this in Postman everything works perfect. So I'm pretty sure that my JSON is valid. 
The problem occurs when I try to execute the POST request in PHP via curl. So I think the problem is in the curl request. I use the same headers and body in my curl request as in Postman. When I execute my code, I get the following error:

```html
<pre><pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr">
<b>object</b>(<i>stdClass</i>)[<i>297</i>]
  <i>public</i> 'timestamp' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'2016-05-20'</font> <i>(length=10)</i>
  <i>public</i> 'status' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color="#4e9a06">400</font>
  <i>public</i> 'error' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Bad Request'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
  <i>public</i> 'exception' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException'</font> <i>(length=66)</i>
  <i>public</i> 'message' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'skills': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@74565e86; line: 1, column: 8]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'skills': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@74565e86; line: 1, column: 8]'</font> <i>(length=376)</i>
  <i>public</i> 'path' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'/task/solve'</font> <i>(length=11)</i>
</pre></pre>
```

The error says that he expects ('true', 'false' or 'null') but actually I need to send an array.
Here you can also find the code that I'm trying to execute:

```
 public function sendDataToCreatePlanning($resource, $apiKey, $apiSecret, $smappyworldPlanningData) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://serverpath/task/solve');

    // create header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
     array("Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($apiKey . ":" . $apiSecret),
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json",
           )
    );

    $arr =array(
            'solverType' => null,
            'solveTime' => null,
            'status' => null,
            'username' => null,
            //'hook' => null,
            'skills' => $smappyworldPlanningData['skills'],
            'employees' => $smappyworldPlanningData['active_users'],
            'dates' => null,
            'timeBlocks' => $smappyworldPlanningData['timeBlocks'],
            'tasks' => $smappyworldPlanningData['tasks'],
            'assignments' => $smappyworldPlanningData['assignments'],
            'blocksPerDay' => 95
            );

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "XXX");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
        http_build_query($arr));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

    $json_payload = curl_exec($ch);

    if (!$json_payload) { echo curl_error($ch); }
    else {
        curl_close($ch);

        $dataAr = json_decode($json_payload);

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($dataAr);
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;

       echo "send data for planning succesfully!";

        return $dataAr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is a rest api, then shouldn't you go for `json_encode($arr)` instead of `http_build_query($arr)`? Like here: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl